# RTF Color Table looping through all colors

Tags: c#, colors, rtf

I have a RichTextBox. I have added RTF formatting (mainly a color table) to this RichTextBox. When I first Append text to it, it loops through all* the colors of the color table.

*It starts with applying color0, then color1, then color2, etc until all the colors in the color table have been applied OR if the text that is being output has one of those colors already - in that case it stops this "looping" and continues as intended. See screenshot for example.

Here is the code:

```
    private void populateColorCodeDictionary() {
        startRTFString = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0;}}" +
        @"{\colortbl 
            ;

            \red0\green0\blue0;
            \red170\green0\blue0;
            \red0\green170\blue0;
            \red128\green128\blue0;
            \red0\green0\blue128;
            \red128\green0\blue128;
            \red0\green128\blue128;
            \red127\green127\blue127;

            \red85\green85\blue85;
            \red255\green0\blue0;
            \red0\green255\blue0;
            \red255\green255\blue0;
            \red0\green0\blue255;
            \red255\green0\blue255;
            \red0\green255\blue255;
            \red255\green255\blue255;
        }";

        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[0;30m", @"\cf1");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[0;31m", @"\cf2");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[0;32m", @"\cf3");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[0;33m", @"\cf4");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[0;34m", @"\cf5");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[0;35m", @"\cf6");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[0;36m", @"\cf7");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[0;37m", @"\cf8");

        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[1;30m", @"\cf9");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[1;31m", @"\cf10");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[1;32m", @"\cf11");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[1;33m", @"\cf12");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[1;34m", @"\cf13");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[1;35m", @"\cf14");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[1;36m", @"\cf15");
        colorCodeDictionary.Add("\x1b[1;37m", @"\cf16");

        /*
        \x1b[0;30m  =   cf1     =   black
        \x1b[0;31m  =   cf2     =   red
        \x1b[0;32m  =   cf3     =   green
        \x1b[0;33m  =   cf4     =   brown
        \x1b[0;34m  =   cf5     =   blue
        \x1b[0;35m  =   cf6     =   purple
        \x1b[0;36m  =   cf7     =   cyan
        \x1b[0;37m  =   cf8     =   gray

        \x1b[1;30m  =   cf9     =   darkGray
        \x1b[1;31m  =   cf10    =   light Red
        \x1b[1;32m  =   cf11    =   light green
        \x1b[1;33m  =   cf12    =   yellow
        \x1b[1;34m  =   cf13    =   light blue
        \x1b[1;35m  =   cf14    =   indigo
        \x1b[1;36m  =   cf15    =   light cyan
        \x1b[1;37m  =   cf16    =   white
        */
    }
```

The above method sets up the variables. The most interesting part is the startRTFString variable.

```
    private void updateOutputWindow(string text) {
        string newText = string.Empty;

        if (InvokeRequired) {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
                updateOutputWindow(text);
            }));
        }
        else {
            newText = startRTFString;
            newText += rtb_outputWindow.Rtf;
            newText += replaceAnsiColorCodes(text);

            rtb_outputWindow.Rtf = newText;
        }
    }
```

The above method outputs text to the RichTextBox.

```
    private string replaceAnsiColorCodes(string inData) {
        string returnString = inData;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in colorCodeDictionary) {
            returnString = returnString.Replace(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }

        returnString = returnString.Replace("\r", @"\line");               //Newline
        returnString = returnString.Replace("\x1b[0;1m", "");            //Bold

        returnString = returnString.Replace("\x1b[0m", @"\cf16 ");      //Reset

        return returnString;
    }
```

The above method converts ANSI codes into RTF color codes. (As well as newline and bold. I have chosen to set bold to be nothing, as of now.)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        updateOutputWindow("\x1b[0mline" + i.ToString());
    }
```

The above is just a little loop that I run as soon as the application has started. It is for testing purposes and can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image: A screenshot showing the incorrect applying of colors]

Above is a screenshot of the issue. As you can see, the first 15 lines of text all have different colors. They should all have the same, default, color (in my case white.) After the "looping" is done, it continues to work as intended; applying the correct color to the text.

It should be noted that the line above the first (line0) is empty. The color table starts with black, so line0 should be black colored, and line1 should be dark red. Don't know why it's not following it's own rules.

Here is another test I ran:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        updateOutputWindow("\x1b[0;34mline" + i.ToString());  //This time I changed the color to be dark blue
    }
```

[image: Second test]

As you can see: the "looping" happened until it ran into the same color, and it kept going with that color.

I have no idea why this happens or what causes it. My guess is that I have messed up the RTF "script" somehow. Does anyone know of a solution? (I don't want ANY of this color table looping to happen. I want it to output the default color, unless there is a color code present - in that case I want that color to be presented.)

EDIT:
I added this bit of code to the method updateOutputWindow `MessageBox.Show(newText);`. Below is the screenshot of the result:

[image: Screenshot of third debug test]

As you can see from the screenshot above the RichTextBox has some kind of "default RTF code" already in-place. -This default code gets added ontop of my "custom RTF code". It doesn't seem to interfere with the color table, though. (Unless this is what is casing the issue at hand, in that case it most certainly is interfering, but in a very specific, one-time way.)

EDIT #2: If I continue to run this method over and over again, the RTF-code doesn't get added for each additional run. It gets added once (at the very top) and then no more. I think that is a good thing, and I believe it is caused by how RichTextBoxes natively handles RTF code.

Comment: You could write manually in Wordpad what you want to appear in your app, and then open the document in plain text editor. For newline use Shift+Enter instead of Enter. I did that just now, and I don't see any of those `\x1b[0` codes.

Comment: I could. But my application is a client which connects to a server. The server is not mine, so I cannot control what it sends to my client. I have to deal with the ANSI codes, sadly.

Comment: Take a look at [termsharp](https://github.com/antmicro/termsharp). Maybe you could use it as is for your needs (just ignore the `xwt` folder, if you don't use `xwt`).

Comment: _newText += rtb_outputWindow.Rtf;_ this prefixes the valid Rtf with a new table. shouldn't you insert the table into the Rtf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting terminal codes (or as you call them ANSI codes) to RTF format. Text that you give to `updateOutputWindow` contains `\x1b[0;34m`, but in `updateOutputWindow` there is no `Replace` line for that terminal code. You have something similar, but not exactly that. As a result a terminal code is now part of RTF, so who knows what happens. Must deal with all terminal codes (replace or remove).

Also, the following code seems strange to me:

```
newText = startRTFString;
newText += rtb_outputWindow.Rtf;
newText += replaceAnsiColorCodes(text);

rtb_outputWindow.Rtf = newText;
```

It seems that `rtb_outputWindow.Rtf` will grow with every function call, adding new `startRTFString` every time. Instead of the code above I propose the following (`myStuff` is a property, like `startRTFString`):

```
myStuff = myStuff + replaceAnsiColorCodes(text);
rtb_outputWindow.Rtf = startRTFString + myStuff;
```

Comment: All the ANSI codes are removed through the method replaceAnsiColorCodes, so none of them should be in the RichTextBox. It is true that the contents of the RichTextBox grows longer and longer the more data is sent. (I have another function which later removes lines of code, when it reaches a certain point - in order to keep memory usage down.) This might not be the best practice, however.

Comment: @Phrosen I am not talking about adding stuff at the end of RTF, but at the beginning. `startRTFString` gets repeated in the beginning of the RTF. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: I ran another test and added the results (with screenshot) to the Original Post. Just as you say the "existing RTF-stuff" gets added to "my RTF-stuff". Not sure if that's what cases the problem or not, nor how to remove it.

Comment: The solution would be to keep track of your stuff, not in `.Rtf` property, but in your own separate property `.MyStuff`. You add new stuff to `MyStuff`, and then set `Rtf` to `startRTFString + MyStuff`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand exactly how you mean. Could you show me an example, and  then I can try testing it out?